# Python working with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I've managed to finally figure out how to select a portion of a pandas dataframe, but now I am lost on how to use the data with in it. I want to be able to add together all of the entries within a minute.

```
for minute in rrule.rrule(rrule.MINUTELY, dtstart=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"T15:30","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), until=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"T22:00","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")):
            temp = pageData[(pageData['time']>=minute)&(pageData['time']<minute+timedelta(seconds=60))]
            print(temp)
```

Comment: Show example input and output, with complete working example code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. What I needed was a loop cycling through the created subpandas (whatever you call them).

```
#Refrences
from time import *
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import timedelta
import urllib.request as web
import pandas as pd
import os

forToday = 'http://netfonds.no/quotes/tradedump.php?csv_format=csv&paper='
dateToday = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime())
#dateToday = "2014-10-07"

def pullToday(exchange,stock):
    hold=[]
    fileName=('data/'+exchange+'/'+stock+'/'+dateToday+'.txt')
    try:
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(fileName)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fileName))
    except OSError:
        print("Something went very wrong. Review the dir creation section")

    pageBuffer=web.urlopen(forToday+stock+'.'+exchange)
    pageData=pd.read_csv(pageBuffer,usecols=['time','price','quantity'])
    for i in pageData.index:
        pageData['time'][i]=pd.datetime.strptime(pageData['time'][i],'%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')

    print(hold)                
    #pageData = pageData.set_index('time',drop=False)
    for minute in rrule.rrule(rrule.MINUTELY, dtstart=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"T15:30","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), until=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"T21:58","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")):
        temp = pageData[(pageData['time']>=minute)&(pageData['time']<minute+timedelta(seconds=60))]
        volume=0
        priceSum=0
        low=123456
        high=0
        for i in temp.index:
            volume+=temp['quantity'][i]
            priceSum+=temp['quantity'][i]*temp['price'][i]
            if temp['price'][i]>high:
                high=temp['price'][i]
            if temp['price'][i]<low:
                low=temp['price'][i]
        priceSum/=volume
        hold.append([minute,volume,low,high,round(priceSum,4)])

    minute=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"T21:59","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
    temp = pageData[(pageData['time']>=minute)&(pageData['time']<minute+timedelta(seconds=180))]
    volume=0
    priceSum=0
    low=123456
    high=0
    for i in temp.index:
        volume+=temp['quantity'][i]
        priceSum+=temp['quantity'][i]*temp['price'][i]
        if temp['price'][i]>high:
            high=temp['price'][i]
        if temp['price'][i]<low:
            low=temp['price'][i]
    priceSum/=volume
    hold.append([minute,volume,low,high,round(priceSum,4)])

    compiledData=pd.DataFrame(hold ,columns=['TimeStamp', 'Volume', 'Low', 'High', 'Average'])
    #for i in compiledData.index:
        #compiledData['TimeStamp'][i]-=pd.datetime.strptime(dateToday+"TZ06","%Y-%m-%dTZ%H")
    print(compiledData)
    dataFile = open(fileName,'w')
    dataFile.write('#Format: Timestamp;Volume;Low;High;Median\n')
    dataFile.close()
    pageData.to_csv(fileName,index=False,sep=';',mode='a',header=False)

def getList(fileName):
    stockList = []
    file = open(fileName+'.txt', 'r').read()
    fileByLines = file.split('\n')
    for eachLine in fileByLines:
        if '#' not in eachLine:
            lineByValues = eachLine.split('.')
            stockList.append(lineByValues)
    return stockList

start_time = time()

stockList = getList('stocks')
#for eachEntry in stockList:
#    pullToday(eachEntry[0],eachEntry[1])

pullToday('O','AAPL')

delay=str(round((time()-start_time)))
print('Finished in ' + delay)
```

Comment: You don't need that loop (looping is almost never needed/a goog idea). E.g. you can simply do `volume = temp['quantitiy'].sum()`

Comment: I also needed to multiply each trade price by its volume. The only way I knew how was with a loop.

Comment: Just `temp['quantity']*temp['price']` outside the loop?